# How to protect exposed Firebase Realtime Database configuration with no user authentication?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am creating a web-based game and using Firebase (Realtime Database) to store the leaderboard score data.

I am wondering how you usually go about securing your Firebase configuration information.

I know that you can restrict Firebase using security rules, but this looks to be mostly related to user authentication, which my app does not have (or need). The API key and Database URL are stored in .env files, but of course, this becomes exposed when it is compiled.

My concern is - what is to stop somebody from inspecting the compiled JavaScript to see the code used to interact with the database and push their own scores to the leaderboard using this code? Is this something to be concerned about?

Are there any rules to only allow certain URLs to interact with the data for example?

My current rules follow:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Of course, this is not ideal, but I need to be able to write (to post new scores) and read to display them on the leaderboard.

Any help and thoughts on this would be appreciated.

Comment: "push their **own** scores to the leaderboard" how do you identify the users and know to whom belongs a given score?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Users do not have to be authenticated to play. At the end of a game, you enter your desired username and email address to submit to the leaderboard. The form data is then captured and posted to the Firebase database along with the score.

Comment: Without auth, there is really no way to control direct access to the database.  Your rules simply allow anyone with an internet connection to fully modify the entire database. You could apply Firebase App Check, but that does not give 100% guarantees about protection. It just understands how to stop some patterns of abuse.